# why cant i delete a character in the input field

Tags: javascript, html, dom

im creating a function to automatically add a `]` when the user presses `[` on the input field which works perfectly

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");

function add(){
  if(input.value === "["){
  input.value = "[]";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input" oninput="add()">
```

but after i input `[` and the input value becomes `[]`, i cant press the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key to delete the "]" and i have to use <kbd>delete</kbd> key to delete it from the back, why is it so?

Comment: Because when you press the backspace it will call `add()`

Comment: @Chaska ah yes i just realise it, how can i solve that problem?

Comment: A solution here is to update your code to use the more modern Event Listener API and read the data associated with the event (aka the key that was pressed that triggered the event) and make a decision to process the input a certain way based on whether the key pressed was “backspace” or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a really common problem to solve, there was a post before about this, but solution for your problem should look like this:

```js
const brackets = new Map([
  ['{', '}'],
  ['[', ']'],
  ['(', ')']
]);
    
const input =document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const origin = e.target;
    const pos = origin.selectionStart;
    const val = [...origin.value];
    
    const char = val.slice(pos-1, pos)[0];
    const bracket = brackets.get(char);
    
    if (bracket) {
      val.splice(pos, 0, bracket);
      origin.value = val.join('');
      origin.selectionEnd = pos;
    }
});
```

```html
<input class="input">
```

Feel free to ask if you don't understand something :)

Comment: ugh, that doesn't quite work, because, if your selection is  [SOMESTRINK_HERE_]]]] and you delete SOMESTRINK, a bracket is added at the end (where _HERE_ is where your cursor sits)

Answer (score 1):

Because writing "[" can't be distinguished from deleting "]" where the resulting input value evaluates to "[" .

To find out if a character has been deleted, add the event as a parameter to add

```
function add(event) ...
```

and check if `event.data` equals to "null".

```
function add(event) {
 if(event.data == null) return;
 // the rest of your code
}
```

and add the event parameter to oninput:

```
<... oninput="add(event)"> ...
```

Comment: how can i solve that problem so i can delete the "]"?